# How to run my django project in dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx?

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to run dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx with my django project.

https://github.com/dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx

---

1.I replaced 'app' folder by my django project folder.

2.Comment out this line form Dockerfile

```
#RUN django-admin.py startproject mailzon /home/docker/code/app/
```

3.`docker build -t my_app_name .`

4.`docker run -d -p 80:80 my_app_name`

Then I opened http://127.0.0.1/
I got error message. 
[ **Internal Server Error** ]

last line of the manual.

> uWSGI chdirs to /app so in uwsgi.ini you will need to make sure the
>   python path to the wsgi.py file is relative to that.

I think I need this setting. but I'm not sure about uWSGI and this setting.
What should I do next...?

Please tell me how to resoleve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there's something wrong when you "replaced 'app' folder [with your] django project folder". The dockerfile is configured to refer to that directory by the name `/.../app`, and if you replace it with `/.../myproject` it'll fail to find it. You probably want to edit the `uwsgi.ini` file to point to the new app folder's name. That is probably the only change you'll need, but there might be other references to the original `/.../app` path that need to get tweaked as well.

Comment: Thank you for the replay.I add my project in to app folder. and I added this 2 line 
`chdir = /home/docker/code/app/
wsgi-file = /home/docker/code/app/mailzon/wsgi.py`
on uwsgi.ini .it's works now!